# Is there a word for a list of all the parts required to construct something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Recipes are lists of ingredients that make something.

A glossary is a list of words used in a book for reference.

Agenda is a list of items to be discussed in a meeting.

_______ is a list of all parts required in order to construct something.

Is there a single word that goes in _____?

As an example, if I wanted to build a tennis court I’d need a list of all the parts (court, rackets, ball, net, metal pipes, fencing).  Not the instructions mine you of how to construct and play, but the list of all the parts and components required to build that thing.

Comment: "Parts list" is the most common term.

Comment: Actually, a list of all the ingredients is only one part of a "recipe," which is far more than just a list of ingredients but also includes quantities of ingredients needed, the name, and a complete set of instructions. A list of ingredients on the back of a food label, for example, is *not* called a "recipe." So there actually is no word for that list, except maybe "ingredients," which correspondingly for construction would be simply "parts," like you said. Construction's equivalent of a "recipe" would be maybe "blueprints" or "building plans," which generally include a parts/materials list.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman good spot. OP says "Not the instructions mine *[sic]* you."

Comment: To construct something as in a building? Or like a machine?

Comment: _Parts list_ (which is certainly the most common term) is a fixed phrase in that the first word is plural, which is normally not allowed (compare *_shoes store_, *_hands cream_, etc). It's short for _list of parts_, but _shoe store_ is short for _store for shoes_, and they're sold in pairs, but it still hasta be singular.

Comment: I have not the heart to suggest as an answer the obvious phrase "components list", which you have implied in your text anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sometimes called a

> **Bill of materials**
> ... a list of the raw materials, sub-assemblies, intermediate assemblies, sub-components, parts, and the quantities of each needed to manufacture an end product.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials).

For a single word, it is commonly abbreviated as **BOM**. Another single word with a slightly different meaning is

> **inventory**
> A complete list of items such as property, goods in stock, or the contents of a building.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inventory).

Comment: Or Bill of Quantities (BOQ) in building construction.